# Sending Mail Using Amazon SES (Simple Email Service) with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services

How can I configure my CodeIgniter application to send email using Amazon SES (Simple Email Service)?

Comment: so you nothing tried yet???

Comment: The email class will be what you're looking for. http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/email.html We can help you, if you run into a problem. We're not going to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this in your controller function write this code

```
$this->load->library('email');

$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    'smtp_user' => 'YOUR SMTP USERNAME',
    'smtp_pass' => 'YOUR SMTP PASSWORD',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'mailtype' => 'html'
);

$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->print_debugger();

$this->email->from('YOUR_EMAIL_ID', 'Test From');
$this->email->to('email@example.com', 'Test To');
$this->email->subject('Test');
$this->email->message('test');        
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->send();
```

for more info check this link http://only4ututorials.blogspot.in/2014/07/how-to-send-mail-using-codeigniter-and.html how to send mail with SMTP